# CreateInputLayout failing

Tags: directx-11, vertex-shader

I have spent a long time away from DirectX11 so I'm unfamiliar with the error I'm getting.
I am creating a layout description and then moving on to create an input layout, however it crashes at that point.

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] = 
    {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"DIMENSIONS", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"INACTIVE", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"ACTIVE", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    };
```

this is how I create the layout

```
Assert(_pDevice->CreateInputLayout(layout, _uiNumElements, CompileData.Data, CompileData.uiDataSize, &m_pVertexLayout))
```

this is the line it is crashing on.

If anybody could shed some light on what the possible reasons are it would be great. Cheers.

Comment: How come "layout" isn't referenced in the CreateInputLayout call? If you turn on the D3D11 Debug Layer on device creation it will give you an error. What is that error?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained further. My CreateInputLayout is a function, and is passed through as _Desc.

layout = _Desc in this case. I'll rename it in my question so it is easier to grasp for others

Comment: Using the debug layer I managed to sort out the error myself. The problem was I was referencing the wrong .cso file. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was figured out using the D3D11 Debug Layer as suggested by Adam Miles.
Simply chucked this into the device creation:

```
#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)  
    CreateDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
```

It turned out I was referencing an old .cso file and not the most recent one.